# Where do I find Malena after she runs away?

Tags: the-witcher-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Witcher 2 (sidequest spoilers) - Where did Malena run off to?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22661/the-witcher-2-sidequest-spoilers-where-did-malena-run-off-to)

So I decided to be nice to Malena this time around and let her go from the guards even though she was clearly guilty. Unfortunately, in spite of my amazing generosity, she decided to send the Scoia'tel after me anyways. Even more regrettably, she ran off while I was busy keeping myself from dying. Now I need to find her again, and that's not exactly easy; there's a whole forest to search and I have no idea where to start.

Where do I find Malena?